# Power Query - how to connect to sharepoint list using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, sharepoint, power-query

anybody knows how to connect to SharePoint Folder using VBA for Power Query? I need to perform ETL(Extract,Transform & Load) process using Power Query, and would like to use VBA to automate the process. However I'm stuck at the connection. The Power Query steps was completed manually, the steps are the same for every month except the folder path.

My plan was to only update the folder path and use the Refresh All function provided by Excel.

I had found a related article that automates Power Query using VBA, but it does not show how to connect to external sources (e.g. SharePoint).

URL: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1

I tried using `sendkey` to connect to SharePoint Folder, but `sendkey` stops after the dialog appears(finished loading).

Any suggestion and help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with Power Query is that the connection and the query is built **in Power Query** and then refreshed on demand. VBA does not come into play when creating the query. That would defeat the purpose of Power Query.

What you **can** do with VBA is automate the refresh of the query, but there are some built-in settings that can do that without VBA.

Edit: It looks like the requirement for VBA comes from the need to keep file paths for the Power Query dynamic. You can parametrise file paths in Power Query. That does not even require VBA. Use a parameter table, use the Excel worksheet function Cell() to get the path of the current file and use a function in M to read that as the parameter of the Source string. Google fnGetParameter to see how. Then none of your file paths need to be hard wired into the query.

Comment: Yes, while searching, I found the build-in setting you mention. Does changing file path also consider creating query? Sorry if it sound stupid, just want to make sure I understand it.

Comment: The formula for the path looks like this. `= Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Folder Path] = "https://"))`.

Comment: I also added an URL about using VBA to automate Power Query. My idea was actually from there.

Comment: What is your use case? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: That is highly specialized code for very rare situations. If you are just starting with Power query you may want to learn to walk before you try a marathon run.

Comment: I am using Power Query for analyzing purpose. This is done monthly, and the files are stored in different folders. If I'm able to use VBA to automatically change the file path based on cell values, it would be alot easier for other users. As they don't know how to use Power Query.

Comment: I added a Power Query suggestion for that scenario.